# Cannot set proxy port with Firefox Webdriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver

This is the code I am using to start Firefox via Selenium Webdriver (Java):

```
private FirefoxDriver getfox(String pr) {
    String geckoPath = "/opt/driver";
    String browserPath = "/opt/browser";
    String h = pr.split(":")[0];
    String p = pr.split(":")[1];

    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", geckoPath);

    FirefoxProfile fp;
    fp = new FirefoxProfile();

    System.out.println("setting proxy " + h + ", port " + p);
    fp.setPreference("network.proxy.http", h);
    fp.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", p);

    FirefoxOptions fo = new FirefoxOptions();
    fo.setProfile(fp);
    fo.setBinary(browserPath);

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fo);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return driver;
}
```

However, when I enter `about:config` in the started browser and check the settings then only the proxy host has been changed. The `http_port` is set to `0`. When I check my IP by navigating, e.g.,

```
Webdriver driver = getfox("host.proxy.server:port");
String address = "https://www.find-ip.net";
//String address = "http://www.find-ip.net";
System.out.println("navigating to " + address);
driver.get(address);
System.out.println("searching elements");
String selector = ("div.ipcontent.pure-u-13-24");

List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(selector));

for (WebElement w : elems) {
    System.out.println(w.getText());
}
```

to `http(s)://www.find-ip.net` then I see my real IP address. The values I am passing are correct. I have no problem setting that proxy in HtmlUnit driver.

The versions involved are:

- Selenium 3.6.0
- Firefox 45.9.0
- geckodriver 19.0

Is there anything I need to change?

Comment: From here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases, is recommended to use Firefox 55.0 (and greater)

Answer (score 0):

With geckodriver **v0.19.0** [is recommended](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to use **Firefox 55.0 (and greater)**.

Update your browser and re-try.

Comment: FF 55 does not work at all. It still does not change the proxy and it also does not even navigate to the address.